# Cannot make Access 2010 accde from Access 2007 accdb

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a bit of a problem and could really use some help. My organization recently migrated from Office 2007 to Office 2010. I had a database that I developed using Access 2007 (using the .accdb database file type). Throughout the migration process, I was still making updates to my database. All the updates were made via an Office 2007 machine and everything worked on the 2010 systems that I deployed it to, as well as the 2007 boxes.  The problem now is that since all the computers are officially on 2010, I cannot seem to create an Accde file from Access 2010. The error I receive is: " The command or action 'MakeMDEFile' isn't available now."  * You may be in a read-only database or an unconverted database from an earlier version..." The code is compiled with no errors and my references are good.

I have tried to re-compile the code, re-name the wizards in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ" folder and let them re-install, and import all my objects into a new database based on this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn602608%28v=office.14%29.aspx; all to no avail.I do not have any web content or anything Access 2010 specific, as I only made adjustments to the things I created in 2007. I did read that Access must be compiled on the same version that it was created on, but I thought since both 2007 and 2010 use the .accdb file format it would be compatible? Any advice on this? Thank you.

---

Thank you for your quick answer! That worked great. I was able to successfully export my DB using the code and I also imported all the objects with the exception of the queries. (I was able to create the accde.) Because I have so many objects, I used a script to import everything. The problem I am experiencing now is with my SQL queries. The export script named the text files a little different for the SQL queries and I don't know how to handle them. Below is my code that worked for the rest of the objects:

```
    Public Sub batchImport_queries()
    On Error GoTo batchImport_Err

    Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object, objF1 As Object
    Dim strFolderPath As String  

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dbexport\queries\"
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Set objFiles = objFolder.files  

    For Each objF1 In objFiles

    objF1.Name = Right(objF1.Name, Len(objF1.Name) - 6)'strips "Query_"
    objF1.Name = Left(objF1.Name, Len(objF1.Name) - 3) 'strips ".txt"
    Application.Application.LoadFromText acQuery, objF1.Name, strFolderPath & objF1.Name

    Next  

    Set objF1 = Nothing
    Set objFiles = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFS = Nothing

    batchImport_Exit:

    Exit Sub

    batchImport_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume batchImport_Exit

    End Sub
```

That worked for queries like: "Query_qryAvailable.txt" but the SQL ones look like this: "Query_~sq_cCIPSSubform~sq_RosterSubform.txt". It seems to be encapsulating "~sq_c" around the first part of the query name and then the form/subform/or control that is associated with it at the last part of the filename...or I could be completely off. I can't figure out the pattern. Some of them have "~sq_f" instead, only at the leading part.(I'm guessing those are for forms?) Anyway, is there a better way to format the file name (if that's what has to be done) to remove those to my original query names and import correctly? Please let me know if that doesn't make sense. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to export an Access database to text files, see here: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=99179.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportDatabaseObjects()
On Error GoTo Err_ExportDatabaseObjects

    Dim db As Database
    'Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim d As Document
    Dim c As Container
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sExportLocation As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    sExportLocation = "C:\Temp\" 'Do not forget the closing back slash! ie: C:\Temp\

    For Each td In db.TableDefs 'Tables
        If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".txt", True
        End If
    Next td

    Set c = db.Containers("Forms")
    For Each d In c.Documents
        Application.SaveAsText acForm, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Form_" & d.Name & ".txt"
    Next d

    Set c = db.Containers("Reports")
    For Each d In c.Documents
        Application.SaveAsText acReport, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Report_" & d.Name & ".txt"
    Next d

    Set c = db.Containers("Scripts")
    For Each d In c.Documents
        Application.SaveAsText acMacro, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Macro_" & d.Name & ".txt"
    Next d

    Set c = db.Containers("Modules")
    For Each d In c.Documents
        Application.SaveAsText acModule, d.Name, sExportLocation & "Module_" & d.Name & ".txt"
    Next d

    For i = 0 To db.QueryDefs.Count - 1
        Application.SaveAsText acQuery, db.QueryDefs(i).Name, sExportLocation & "Query_" & db.QueryDefs(i).Name & ".txt"
    Next i

    Set db = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing

    MsgBox "All database objects have been exported as a text file to " & sExportLocation, vbInformation

Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects:
    Exit Sub

Err_ExportDatabaseObjects:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects

End Sub
```

If the principle still holds, you should be able to import the resulting objects to a fresh database.  If there are any problems with permissions, that should become evident in the text files, but normally this strips all permissions.